# Name lookup from secondary DNS server, if primary returns a non-reachable IP address

Tags: dns, bind

- My Corporate Mail server(housed at HQ) is accessible to my zonal office(geographically located in a different state) via a point-to-point leased line on a LAN IP address say **192.168.1.100**.
- Additionally, it is also accessible via the web by a FQDN say **www.mail.example.com**
- In the Zonal Office I have setup a **Bind** name-server. 
  In its configuration I have made a zone for www.mail.example.com to translate to the LAN-IP address i.e. 192.168.1.100, in order to save on the internet bandwidth while accessing the mail.

Now the problem I am facing is that the leased-line goes down once in a while and Although the mail-server is accessible via web and also In my bind configuration I have made Google's DNS 8.8.8.8 as **forwarder**, **users when type www.mail.ecil.co.in they get redirected to 192.168.1.100**.

Is there a way I can tell bind, **if the IP address for this FQDN can't be reached, try to resolve it's domain-name via 8.8.8.8.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In the file `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` change line `dns=dnsmasq` to `# dns=dnsmasq`. Then in file `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` find line `# supersede domain-name-servers` , and change that to `supersede domain-name-servers xxx.xx.xxx.xxx. yyy.yy.yyy.yyy` , where x and y are numbers of the ip address for the dns servers you want to use.